# Easy way to load assembly from memory

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I have an application uses some external assemblyes (like htmlAgilityPack etc).
Can I load this assemblyes from memory (before main code starts) without complex modify of my application?
For example main application downloads from server assembly like byte array, loads it and start main code.
How to solve it without hard modify application code?

added.

For example, Im using HtmlDocument from HtmlAgilityPack. If im not set reference to HtmlAgilityPack application will not be compilled. How can I use Assembly.Load in my code to load HtmlAgilityPack and use it types in application?

Comment: please note [assembly tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/assembly/info) is for the family of assembly languages and not net-assemblies...

Comment: Have you looked at the [Assembly.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h538bck7(v=vs.110).aspx) family of methods? That's pretty much the answer right there :)

Comment: You also probably want to look at the [AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve(v=vs.110).aspx) event as well - basically, this event get's fired when an assembly could not be found, and it will then give you an opportunity to download your assembly, load it, and then return it.

Comment: RB, very interesting! Can i use this event to load assembly "by hand" if it not exists in appication directory?

Comment: I've posted some code to show using this method to load from a plugins folder. It should be easy to change it to download a byte array from a web-service or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will handle a failed attempt to load a DLL by searching an extra folder (PluginsFolder in this case). You could change it to download a `Byte[]` from a web-service and then load it using the appropriate [Assembly.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h538bck7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Note the following points:

- The code should go in your application entry point (e.g. your `Main` method).
- We lock the resolution procedure as it could be called on different threads.
- We store a list of previously resolved assemblies to improve performance.
- There are issues if you attempt to use this in ASP.NET. Issues like "it doesn't work".

Code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Stores a list of assemblies we have resolved.
/// </summary>
private IDictionary<string, Assembly> resolvedAssemblies = new Dictionary<string, Assembly>();

public Service1()
{
    // Register an assembly resolver to load assemblies from the Plugins folder.
    // This allows plugins to use any dependencies they like.
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) =>
    {
        lock (this.resolvedAssemblies)
        {
            if (!this.resolvedAssemblies.ContainsKey(args.Name))
            {
                //Use the AssemblyName class to get the name
                var name = new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name;

                var file = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Settings.Default.ParsersFolder, name + ".dll"));

                log.Info("Attempting to load assembly " + file);

                if (!File.Exists(file))
                {
                    return null;
                }

                var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(file);

                if (assembly.FullName != args.Name)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                resolvedAssemblies.Add(args.Name, assembly);
            }

            return this.resolvedAssemblies[args.Name];
        }
    };
}
```